# C# LINQ Distinct and ADO.NET EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using ADO.NET EF with Code First approach. I am using :

```
IList<SoleColor> soleColors = SoleColorService.All().ToList();
```

To get list of all records in my `SoleColor` table. What is left is to distinct those result, because there is this column - `SoleCode` and I need only one record for each group of records in the table that use the same `SoleCode`. I went through a lot of articles on this topic but this is my last attempt to find the solution I think must exist. Obviously

```
IList<SoleColor> soleColors = SoleColorService.All().Distinct.ToList();
```

doesn't work for various reasons but still - `soleColors` holds all records/data I need. I just need one more step to filter those records/data so that I keep only one for each `SoleCode`. I don't know if it can be achieved with plain LINQ or some other way. What I think (as newbie) is that it seems a pretty standard job and there shouldn't be need to implement or rewrite existing methods as I saw for a solution in various places.

So - is there a standard way to do this. And if not, at least it seems to me, that this is not something rare so I guess there is a common approach in such cases to deal with.

P.S

Here is the code of my entity related to this:

```
public class SoleColor : Entity
    {
        [Required]
        public long SoleID { get; set; }
        public virtual Sole Sole { get; set; }
        //Some code..
        [NotMapped]
        public string SoleCode
        {
            get
            {
                if (Sole == null)
                    return string.Empty;

                return Sole.Code;
            }
        }
        //Some code...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by grouping:

```
SoleColorService.All()
                .GroupBy(x => x.SoleCode)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```

Update after edit of OP:

Because `SoleCode` is not mapped, you will have to use this code:

```
SoleColorService.All()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Sole == null ? string.Empty : x.Sole.Code)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```

This basically repeats the code of the `SoleCode` property in the query. That isn't really clean, because it violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
An alternative that doesn't violate DRY looks like this:

```
SoleColorService.All()
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.SoleCode)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```

However, this has the disadvantage that it will first fetch *all* rows from the database into the memory of your application and performs the grouping there.

You will have to decide which solution you choose. As I showed, both have disadvantages.

Comment: That, or `Distinct` with custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`. :)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor: As this is going to the database I am reluctant to use that overload. It will vary between providers.

Comment: True, I'm just pointing out that there's a *possibility*. I'd use the version you listed too, especially for 'distinct by one property only'.

Comment: `The specified type member 'SoleCode' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.` Could it be because `SoleCode` is marked as [NotMapped] in my entity (I'll update my code with the entity code) and what should I do in this casa?

Comment: @Leron: Yes, `NotMapped` is the reason. In that case, you will have to transfer everything from the database and perform the grouping in memory. You can achieve this by adding `.AsEnumerable()` before the `.GroupBy`. Alternativly, you can use the mapped property that `SoleCode` uses internally.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but this kind of situations are giving me much trouble I have difficulties even to identify if its pure LINQ or LINQ + lambda - and I see that you work freely with this stuff so could you give me some basic directions how to improve my skills when it comes to such kind of problems?

Comment: @Leron: I am not really sure what you are asking here...?

Comment: Maybe it's not the right place to ask for such kind of things. Thank you very much again I'm gonna use your solution.